# Finding sum of !is.na for different ids

Tags: r, sum, aggregate

I'm trying to calculate the amount of non-NA responses per unique id code in my data. Background: there are 128 trials, but I am calculating 'total correct' based on x/completed trials. So I need to know how many trials were completed out of the 128 per person.

This totals it per person but doesn't incorporate the NA values

```
aggregate(is.na(jatos$response_keyboard_response),by=list(jatos$participantID),FUN=length)
```

I get this, which participant 2 skipped all 54 so it didn't incorporate the NA values

```
Group.1  x
1       fgh621  6
2 hdsafh12304e 54
```

And I tried this and got the sum of !is.na but no group separation

```
sum(!is.na(jatos$response_keyboard_response))
```

And I get this

```
[1] 5
```

And I also tried this

```
setDT(jatos)[,.(non_na=sum(!is.na(jatos$response_keyboard_response))),jatos$participantID]
```

and get this
jatos$participantID non_na
1:        hdsafh12304e      5
2:              fgh621      5

Here is a picture of part of the data, all 5 of the non NA responses belong to ID fgh621 but show up for both[enter image description here
[image]

Answer (score 0):

With your provided data you can get the number of NA's or not NA's (using `!`) with this code:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(participantID) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~sum(is.na(.)))) # ~sum(!is.na(.)) as alternative
```

```
  participantID correct response_keyboard_response count_experimental_trial_sequence response_time_keyboard_response
  <chr>           <int>                      <int>                             <int>                           <int>
1 fgh621              0                          1                                 0                               1
2 hdsafh12304e        0                         14                                 0                              14
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(correct = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), participantID = c("hdsafh12304e", 
"hdsafh12304e", "hdsafh12304e", "hdsafh12304e", "hdsafh12304e", 
"hdsafh12304e", "hdsafh12304e", "hdsafh12304e", "hdsafh12304e", 
"hdsafh12304e", "hdsafh12304e", "hdsafh12304e", "hdsafh12304e", 
"hdsafh12304e", "fgh621", "fgh621", "fgh621", "fgh621", "fgh621", 
"fgh621"), response_keyboard_response = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "right", "left", "left", 
"right", "left", NA), count_experimental_trial_sequence = c(40L, 
41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), response_time_keyboard_response = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1242L, 419L, 
521L, 313L, 226L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Comment: When I try this I get the following: Error in UseMethod("group_by") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "function"